# Universal Windows Apps Navigation

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I feel like I'm being really dumb here....I've just spent the last 2 hours googling what should be a simple problem and yet I can't seem to get it to work. All I'm trying to do is the following:

I've created a universal app project in visual studio and under the project solution I've created a folder called "Pages" in which I have created two blank pages. All I want is for the main page to navigate straight to Page1. Back in the days of Windows Phone 8.1 I would have used the NavigationServices and passed it a Uri. Now it seems I have to use something along the lines of:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page1));
```

that is not working at all - tried removing the folder structure and just navigating to another blank page but it seems like "Page1" is just not recognised. What am I doing wrong?

It seems quite clear I did not descrived the problem very well. Here is my App structure:

[image]

Inside MainPage I have the following code:

```
namespace TrainPuzzle
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a     Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page1));


        }
    }
}
```

I have tried the same code with Pages.Page1 and got a nullexception error. Hopefully this makes more sense

Comment: Compile-time error -  Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'Page1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: you probably need a using statement for page1 namespace.  There should be a light bulb that pops up when you click on that line of code which will show a few ways to fix the issue

Comment: Tried a using that, except it then throws a nullreference exception. If I instantiate an instance of the class "Page1" then typeof complains that it was not expecting a variable....I'm going around in circles.

Comment: you're right. I wasn't very clear. Maybe now you can spot the mistake.

Comment: Did you add using TrainPuzzle.Pages in MainPage code behind?

Comment: Frankly I thought that if I couldn't get form MainPage to Page1 I would have the same problem when trying to get form Page1 to LevelSelect. Seems like that's not the case....Starting on Page1 seems to have fixed if. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Make sure your Page1.xaml and Page1.xaml.cs have the same class name ( `x:class="Page1"` and `public sealed partial class Page1 : Page` )

Answer (score 2):

You cannot navigate in the constructor for a simple reason: *This.Frame* is still null. It get's set once the Page has been navigated to by a frame who to do so has have the instance already.

So you may navigate in the Loaded event.

But as many comments stated: Navigating away from a page before it has even been loaded means that you could have used a different navigation target beforehand and is just a waste of compute resources.

Also, once you activate the NavigationCache, the constructor doesn't get called on the second time the page is displayed, so you should avoid having too many logic in there.